# Three.js - bind a texture to particle

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

My question is how can I bind texture to a particle in 
use of THREE.ParticleCanvasMaterial ?

I mean what is the syntax to bind texture to particle?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use a `ParticleBasicMaterial` and pass in your `Texture` as the map property of the material:

```
var material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'yourTexture.png' ) } );
```

Also, have a look at the [canvas_particle_sprites](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_particles_sprites.html) example. Notice that it's generating a texture on the fly, but you can load your own texture as described above. From experience, the CanvasRenderer is slow with many/large textures.

[image: canvas particles sprites preview]

Answer (score 0):

### Update 2019: ParticleBasicMaterial is deprecated

> ParticleBasicMaterial has been renamed to PointsMaterial.

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/deprecated/DeprecatedList

You need to use PointsMaterial instead of ParticleBasicMaterial

```
 var snowMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
      size: 7,
      blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
      map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("./assets/snowflake.png"),
      //createCircleTexture("#ffffff", 20),
      transparent: true,
      depthWrite: false
    });
```

Alternatively you can use canvas to draw Circular shapes for particle texture as suggest by George:

```
export const createCircleTexture = (color, size) => {
  var matCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  matCanvas.width = matCanvas.height = size;
  var matContext = matCanvas.getContext("2d");
  // create texture object from canvas.
  var texture = new THREE.Texture(matCanvas);
  // Draw a circle
  var center = size / 2;
  matContext.beginPath();
  matContext.arc(center, center, size / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  matContext.closePath();
  matContext.fillStyle = color;
  matContext.fill();
  // need to set needsUpdate
  texture.needsUpdate = true;
  // return a texture made from the canvas
  return texture;
};
```

**Test Image**

[image]

**Result**

[image]